# GraphStream: Interactive Web Application

Tags: javascript, java, d3.js, websocket, graphstream

I'm trying to develop an interactive web application using GraphStream. The idea is to run a couple of community detection algorithms on graphs and visualize them. I wish to use D3.js as graph rendering framework and use GraphStream library in a java websocket server ( Tomcat ) that runs the algorithms. I wish to know if GraphStream already has websocket capabilities that could directly talk to client ( browser ) websocket endpoint. Suggestions for a more correct or feasbile architecture are also welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great idea. There is a WebSocket implementation that provides GraphStream's event model to the browser. It implements a network protocol, [GS-NetStream](https://github.com/graphstream/gs-netstream/wiki/NetStream-Manual).

The actual version is compatible with gs-core v1.3.

You can run the exemples from the [`test/`](https://github.com/graphstream/gs-netstream/tree/master/js/test) folder.

In the test folder, run these commands in that order:

1. Install dependencies : `npm install ws express`
2. Compile the Test1.java with gs-core-1.3 in the classpath: `javac -cp path/to/gs-core-1.3.jar:. Test1.java`
3. Run the node server : `node Test1server.js`
4. Run the Java app :`java -cp path/to/gs-core-1.3.jar Test1`
5. go to http://localhost:8080/Test1.html
6. Use the code in Test1.html as an example for your project

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty much interested and any form of help in getting forward is appreciated.

Comment: Also, It would be great if you could provide some steps to run the examples in https://github.com/graphstream/gs-netstream/tree/master/js/test. I tried running the test1.java and test1.html. But I'm getting errors in test1.java such as 

`code`

Listening?...
Received: GET /gs/stream HTTP/1.1
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "GET /gs/stream HTTP/1.1"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
 at java.lang.Integer.<init>(Integer.java:867)
 at TestServer$1.run(TestServer.java:41)

Comment: I edited my answer. The JS gs-netstream  implementation has been updated. See my edits to help you run the exemples.

Comment: @Yoann I will looking at taking this project too. Any hints/tips that will be nice to know? Thanks